# Backspace KeyboardEvent in Karma test is not triggering ngModelChange

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a directive that does some formatting of a phone number and handles when the user deletes numbers. For some reason this works fine when actually interacting with the input on the page, but if I try to simulate the Backspace key event in a unit test the ngModelChange event never gets fired. If I manually fire it (using an input event) it does not remove the last number in the field as it works in the UI itself.

I've left my console.log calls in.

### phone-mask.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[formControlName][appPhoneMask]',
})
export class PhoneMaskDirective {
  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) {}

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  onModelChange(event) {
    console.log("onModelChange event value: ");
    this.onInputChange(event, false);
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
  keydownBackspace(event) {
    console.log("keydownBackspace");
    this.onInputChange(event.target.value, true);
  }

  onInputChange(event, backspace) {
    let newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');
    console.log("onInputChange: " + newVal);
    let formattedVal = this.formatValue(newVal, backspace);
    console.log("onInputChange (formattedVal): " + formattedVal);
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(formattedVal);
  }

  formatValue(newVal: string, backspace: any): string {
    if (backspace && newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, newVal.length - 1);
    }
    if (newVal.length === 0) {
      newVal = '';
    } else if (newVal.length <= 3) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '($1)');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '($1) $2');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 10) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
    } else if (newVal.length == 11) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,1})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '$1-$2-$3-$4');
    } else if (newVal.length == 12) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,2})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '$1-$2-$3-$4');
    } else if (newVal.length == 13) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '$1-$2-$3-$4');
    } else {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, 10);
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
    }
    console.log("formatValue: " + newVal);
    return newVal;
  }
}
```

### backspace-keypress.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-backspace-keypress',
  templateUrl: './backspace-keypress.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./backspace-keypress.component.css']
})
export class BackspaceKeypressComponent implements OnInit {
  public myGroup = new FormGroup ({
    phoneNumber: new FormControl({})
  });

  constructor() {
    this.myGroup.setValue({
      "phoneNumber": ""
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

### backspace-keypress.component.html

```
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <input required type="text" formControlName="phoneNumber" appPhoneMask data-testid="testBox" />
</div>
```

### backspace-keypress.component.spec.ts

```
import { ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { PhoneMaskDirective } from '../phone-mask.directive';

import { BackspaceKeypressComponent } from './backspace-keypress.component';

describe('BackspaceKeypressComponent', () => {
  let component: BackspaceKeypressComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BackspaceKeypressComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BackspaceKeypressComponent, PhoneMaskDirective ],
      imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BackspaceKeypressComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('detects backspace presses and handles accordingly', fakeAsync(() => {
    const { nativeElement } = fixture;
    const testBox = nativeElement.querySelector('[data-testid="testBox"]');

    component.myGroup.setValue({
      "phoneNumber": "1234567"
    });
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(testBox.value).toBe("(123) 456-7");

    const backspaceEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: "Backspace", cancelable: true});
    testBox.dispatchEvent(backspaceEvent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    expect(testBox.value).toBe("(123) 456");
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my input field, but now the deleting of the last character still works.

Component template:

```html
<input 
  #titleinp 
  type="text" 
  class="col-12 p-2 mb-3 rounded border-1" 
  placeholder="Title" (ngModelChange)="onTitleChange($event)" 
  [ngModel]="this.actualBook.getTitle()" 
  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
>
```

Component ts:

```
onInput(event: Event) {
  console.log('event fired - onInput');
  const inputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  const inputValue = inputElement.value;
    
  if (inputValue.length === 1 && inputValue === '\b') { 
    // \b is backspace
    this.actualBook.setTitle('');
    console.log('empty title - never seen this');
  }
}
onTitleChange(newTitle: string) {
    console.log('event fired - onTitleChange');
    if (newTitle.length === 1 && newTitle === '\b') { // \b is backspace
        this.actualBook.setTitle('');
        console.log('empty title - never seen this');
    } else {
        this.actualBook.setTitle(newTitle);
        console.log('it works always, on the deleting of the last character too');
  }
}
```